# CSS: Gradient only applying to half of background, but background base color applies to whole page?

Tags: html, css, gradient

So what I'm trying to do is to add a slight gradient to the entire website background below the header and navigation bar. I want to add this to the body and simply have no background on the container. What happens is that if I make the container the gradient, it applies to the container and the body is left below as whatever color, or just white space.

If I make the body the gradient, and set the container background to none, I will get an odd darker gradient on the container background, and the correct gradient on the bottom half (the body half) of the page. Here is the code that does this:

My HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="header">

    <h1>stuff</h1>
    <p>more stuff</p>

</div>

<div id="navbar"></div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="main_text">
        main text of site
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#container {
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
overflow: hidden;

background: none;
}
#navbar {
padding: 0px;
height: 30px;
width: auto;
background-position: bottom;
background-color: #000;
}
#main_text {
margin: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 1000px;
border: 1px outset #000;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
background-color: #FFF;
}

#header {
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
background-color: #FFF;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #86b9e0 0%,#2989d8 50%,#0e75c9 100%);       
}
body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5e5e5 0%,#afafaf 53%,#a0a0a0 100%);
}
```

I'm not sure if there's just something really simple I'm missing, or if I should be designing the page in a totally different way. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a link to an online demo (using jsfiddle.net, or something comparable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this to your css:

```
html, body {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;    
}
```

this forces the body to take up at least the height of the viewport.

Check an example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZzArv/

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm. I'm not exactly sure why the container was switching to that odd gradient, but this seems to fix it right up.
Thanks, friend!